# Checking out books in a library management system

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am writing code for a basic library management system, I have a txt file for ID number, book title and then author. I have got to the stage where I have a log in system asking for id numbers etc and I can search for books. Now I need to make it so I can check out the book... I have got it so it will search for the book but then I need to be append the ID number onto the correct book in the txt file. I have got it so at the moment it just appends to the last object. any pointers would be a great help. Thank you.

Present code for searching for books...

```
while True:
    n=float(raw_input('Please enter your ID '))
    if n in range (1000,10000):

    break
print 'ID is incorrect, please try again'


with open("txt.txt") as searchfile:
    found = False
    while not found:
        b=str(raw_input('please enter a book '))
        if b == '':
        break  # allow the search-loop to quit on no input
        for line in searchfile:
            if b in line:
                print line
                found = True
                break
        else:
            print 'Please try again'
            searchfile.seek(0)  # reset file to the beginning for next search


searchfile.close()
```

That all works ^^^ then i got to checking out books and got this following code:

```
find_book=[]
    with open('txt.txt') as input_file:
        lines = [line.rstrip().split('\t')
                 for line in input_file.readlines()]



if(find_book('0',3))==0:
    print 'availabile'
```

Comment: You're not likely to get help here with such a general question. Can you show your current code and give a detailed example of how it doesn't work as you need it to? With that, you might be able to get an answer. As it is, your question is likely to be closed.

Comment: Eek why are you doing this with a text file instead of a database?

Comment: Well i will look into that, but at present i was thinking of reading the file, opening it as a list and defining through classes and doing it that way..

Answer (score 1):

**class Library**

```
Librarians=[["Prashanth","1234"],["Swetha","4321"]]
Students=[["RajaShekar","1111"],["Sandeep","2222"],["Manasa","3333"],["Manoj","4444"],["RamaKrishna","5555"],["Teja","6666"],["Bhavani","7777"],["Sandilya","9999"]]
Rack_Book=[["Physics","Einstin","1000"],["Physics","Einstin","1001"],["Physics","Edison","1002"],["Physics","Einstin","1003"],["Physics","Einstin","1004"],\
      ["Chemistry","Einstin","2000"],["Chemistry","Thamos","2001"],["Chemistry","Einstin","2002"],["Chemistry","Nobel","2003"],["Chemistry","Einstin","2004"]]
Dispatch_Book=[]
def Change_Login(self,name,pin):
    if [name,pin] not in lib.Librarians:
        Librarians=self.Librarians.append([name,pin])
        print("Successfully Changed login details")
    else:
         print("Entered same details only")
def Update_Book(self,name,author,Bid):
    if [name,author,Bid] not in lib.Rack_Book:

        Rack_Book=self.Rack_Book.append([name,author,Bid])
        #print(lib.Rack_Book)
        print("Update Successfully:",[name,author,Bid])
    else:
         print("Book already available with same details")
def Details_Books(self):
    print("--------------------------------------------------")
    print("Book name"," "*9,"Author Name"," "*9,"Book ID")
    print("--------------------------------------------------")


    for i in range(len(lib.Rack_Book)):
        print(lib.Rack_Book[i][0]," "*(20-len(lib.Rack_Book[i][0])),lib.Rack_Book[i][1]," "*(20-len(lib.Rack_Book[i][1])),lib.Rack_Book[i][2])
        print("___________________________________________________")

    print("\nNo of avaliable Books are:",len(lib.Rack_Book))

def Add_Students(self,name,pin):
    if [name,pin] not in lib.Students:
        Students=self.Students.append([name,pin])
        print("Successfully Added with details",[name,pin])
    else:
         print("Students already available with details") 
def Delete_Students(self,name,pin):
    if [name,pin] in lib.Students:
        Students=self.Students.remove([name,pin])
        print("Successfully deleted details",[name,pin])
    else:
         print("No students available with details")    
def Details_Students(self):
    print("-------------------------------")
    print("Sudent name"," "*9,"R.No")
    print("-------------------------------")

    for i in range(len(lib.Students)):
        print(lib.Students[i][0]," "*(20-len(lib.Students[i][0])),lib.Students[i][1])
        print("_______________________________")
    print("\nNo of Students are:",len(lib.Students))
def Collect_Books(self,name,author,Bid):
    if [name,author,Bid] in lib.Rack_Book:
        Dispatch_Book=self.Dispatch_Book.append([name,author,Bid])
        Rack_Book=self.Rack_Book.remove([name,author,Bid])
        print("Book collected succesfully:" ,[name,author,Bid])
    else:
       print("Enter details wrong:")    
def Return_Book(self,name,author,Bid):
    if [name,author,Bid] in lib.Dispatch_Book:
        Dispatch_Book=self.Dispatch_Book.remove([name,author,Bid])
        Rack_Book=lib.Rack_Book.append([name,author,Bid])
        print("Return Successfully:",[name,author,Bid])
    else:
       print("Enter details wrong:")


lib=Library()
print("Welcome to Library")
while(True):
print('''Select your Option
 1:Librarian Login
 2:Student Login
 3:Exit''')

opt1=int(input("Please Enter your option:"))

if opt1==1:
    i=1
    while (i<4):
        usrlib=input("Please Enter your Name:")
        pinlib=input("Please Enter your Login PIN:")

        if [usrlib,pinlib] in lib.Librarians:
            print("Access Granted")
            i=5
            while(True):
                print('''Select your Option
                 0:Change Username or Password   
                 1:Add Books
                 2:Books Details
                 3:Add Students
                 4:Remove Students
                 5:Students details
                 6:Exit or Back''')
                opt2=int(input("Please Enter your option:"))
                if opt2==0:
                    usrlib1=input("Please Enter User Name to chane:")
                    pinlib2=input("Please Enter Login PIN to change:")
                    lib.Change_Login(usrlib1,pinlib2)

                elif opt2==1:
                    name=input("Please Enter your Book Name:")
                    author=input("Please Enter your Book Author:")
                    Bid=input("Please Enter your Book Id:")
                    lib.Update_Book(name.capitalize(),author.capitalize(),Bid)

                elif opt2==2:
                    lib.Details_Books()

                elif opt2==3:
                    name=input("Please Enter Student Name:")
                    pin=input("Please Enter Student R.No:")
                    lib.Add_Students(name.capitalize(),pin)
                elif opt2==4:
                    name=input("Please Enter Student Name:")
                    pin=input("Please Enter Student R.No:")
                    lib.Delete_Students(name.capitalize(),pin)    
                elif opt2==5:
                    lib.Details_Students()
                elif opt2==6:    
                    print("Back to Menu")
                    break
                else:
                    print("Wrong input")
                    continue


        else:
            print("Access Denied \nUser name or PIN Entered wrong")
            print("\nYou have more",(3-i),"attempts")
            i+=1
            if i==4:
                print("Failed login within 3 attempts")
elif opt1==2:
    i=1
    while (i<4):
        usrstd=input("Please Enter your Name:")
        pinstd=input("Please Enter your R.No:")

        if [usrstd,pinstd] in lib.Students:
            print("Access Granted")
            i=5
            while(True):
                print('''Select your Option
                     1:Collect Book
                     2:Return Books
                     3:Exit or Back
                     ''')
                opt2=int(input("Please Enter your option:"))
                if opt2==1:
                    print("Availablie Books are:\n")
                    lib.Details_Books()
                    name=input("Please Enter your Book Name:")
                    author=input("Please Enter your Book Author:")
                    Bid=input("Please Enter your Book Id:")
                    lib.Collect_Books(name.capitalize(),author.capitalize(),Bid)
                elif opt2==2:
                    name=input("Please Enter your Book Name:")
                    author=input("Please Enter your Book Author:")
                    Bid=input("Please Enter your Book Id:")
                    lib.Return_Book(name.capitalize(),author.capitalize(),Bid)
                elif opt2==3:
                    print("Back to Menu")
                    break

                else:
                    print("Wrong input")


        else:
            print("Access Denied \nUser name or PIN Entered wrong")
            print("\nYou have more",(3-i),"attempts")
            i+=1
            if i==4:
                print("Failed login within 3 attempts")

elif opt1==3:
    print("Exit Successfully")
    break

else:
    print("Wrong input")
```

This is Library management program , I take initially some books , some students and two librarians. Librarians can only check book details,student details and they only add or remove student logins. Students login with there details and collect the books from available books ,return books which is taken. If student collect the book , the book details append in to dispatched list and remove from the available list.